# Bind NSTextField's text color to NSColorWell?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, cocoa-bindings

I'm quite new to Cocoa Bindings, but I've seen enough that I'd love to change all my old clunky methods over to it.  For example, I have a `NSColorWell` that changes the text color of some `NSTextField`s in my view. Seems easy in practice, but it's not working.

Here's how my bindings look for my `NSColorWell`:

[image]

And here's my bindings for my `NSTextField`:

[image]

But instead of displaying a color it just displays `NSCalibratedRGBColor...`.  Obviously it's not setting the value of the color to the field, it's just displaying the raw data.

So, after poking around I tried to make my own `NSValueTransformer` by doing this:

```
@interface DataToColor: NSValueTransformer {}
@end
#import "QWDataToColor.h"
@implementation DataToColor
+(Class)transformedValueClass { return [NSColor class]; }
+(BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation { return NO; }
-(id)transformedValue:(id)item {
    NSColor *theColor=nil;
    NSData *theData=[NSData dataWithData:item];
    if (theData != nil)
        theColor=(NSColor *)[NSUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:theData];
    return theColor;
}
@end
```

Then I set that value transformer to my "Value Transformer" area in my bindings in IB.

However, it still gave the same results.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value binding is:

```
An NSString or NSNumber that is displayed as the content of the NSTextField
```

You want to bind the textColor property of your NSTextField, not value.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSTextField.html for the complete list of bindings supported by NSTextField.

Comment: Yep, I just saw that.  How would I go about setting the textColor property through bindings?  This is my first time experiencing this magic.  :)

Comment: Holy cow I don't know how I missed it when it was in plain sight the whole time.  I just needed to scroll down on the bindings pane until I saw the "textColor" property.  Hooked it up and the magic happened!  Thanks.  http://i.imgur.com/iOQlL.png

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple. You can bind things in code equally as well as through IB, and in this case I think this is the only way to do it, because views (in this case, the color well) don't show up as bindable objects in IB*:

```
// Given two appropriately-set-up IBOutlets, tf to the text field,
// and cw to the color well
[tf bind:@"textColor" toObject:cw withKeyPath:@"color" options:nil];
```

It's also possible, and in some cases desirable, such as when you might need to use this value in other places or archive it, to bind each object through an intermediate variable in a controller.

---

<sub>*I would love to be shown wrong about this!</sub>

Comment: Here's the problem.  They're in separate nib files.  How would I create an outlet to my colorwell then?

Comment: Ah. In that case, you _do_ have to do the intermediary thing and bind them through an object that has a presence in both nibs. This is pretty much what the File's Owner proxy object in nibs is all about; that object can connect to everything in the second nib, and is also able to talk to objects in the rest of the project. You should be able to do this in IB.

Comment: @sudo: when I say "do this" I mean "make the two bindings".

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this just seemed to complicated when the answer was in plain sight.  See here: http://i.imgur.com/iOQlL.png  I don't know how I missed that. :)

Comment: @sudo: I assumed that you had already seen it. For my own part, I missed the fact that you were binding to User Defaults. :/

Comment: @Josh: Ah, gotcha.  Oh well, I appreciate your efforts. :)